# Thank You Everyone

Tags: discussion

Judging people's questions and dismissing them as "duplicative" fails to help anyone (except the egos of those passing judgment).

If multiple people are asking the same question, how about posting the answer IN PLAIN ENGLISH (and Spanish) and then PROVIDING A LINK to the information?

That way, you can all save yourselves the time and effort of re-replying to the same questions from non-programmers, AND from having to judge everyone's posts. (You surely must have better things to do.)

Believe me, I am using this forum as a last resort, and I will not be coming back.

Comment: I am sorry you had a bad experience, but, marking questions as duplicate  serves the exact purpose you  are requesting. If your question is being marked as a duplicate, update the question to reflect you have  read the  duplicate and clarify what part you do not understand. Duplicate questions and marking  should allow us to quality control and improve answers. This sort of discussion , IMO, belongs on meta

Comment: This post is about this question: [How do I update Ubuntu 15.04?](//askubuntu.com/q/986984)

Comment: If you think this is a forum, did you take the [tour] to get an idea of the site's format before posting?

Comment: I don't understand. Closing as a duplicate is doing precisely what you are asking for: it is providing a link to the information. That's the whole point. There's nothing dismissive about marking duplicates, it is a way of helping you find your answer.

Answer (score 11):

From the comments [in your original question](https://askubuntu.com/q/986984), it looks like you didn't follow any of the answers in the duplicate question and its answers.

So the best thing to do right now is to follow the answers in the duplicate and if you run into trouble *after having tried them all*, [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), point out where you ran into trouble and we'll adapt the duplicate or write a new answer for a new scenario we've not run into before...

Don' be frustrated that you're not getting all the personal attention you want: this is a Q&A site, not a forum and if it's our considered opinion your problem looks like a duplicate, it probably is in 95% of all cases...

So please *help us in helping you!*

## :-)